# Ruby self and puts

Tags: ruby

If self is the default receiver in ruby and you call 'puts' in an instance method definition, is an instance of the object the receiver of that call?

E.g.

```
    class MyClass
      attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :size

      # initialize, etc (name = String, size = int)

      def full_name
        fn = first_name + " " + last_name 
        # so here, it is implicitly self.first_name, self.last_name
        puts fn 
        # what happens here?  puts is in the class IO, but myClass 
        # is not in its hierarchy (or is it?)
        fn
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely, the current object is the receiver of the method call here. The reason why that works is because the [`Kernel`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel) module defines a `puts` method and is mixed into `Object`, which is the implicit root class of every Ruby class. Proof:

```
class MyClass
  def foo 
    puts "test"
  end
end

module Kernel
  # hook `puts` method to trace the receiver
  alias_method :old_puts, :puts
  def puts(*args)
    p "puts called on %s" % self.inspect
    old_puts(*args)
  end
end

MyClass.new.foo
```

This prints `puts called from #<MyClass:0x00000002399d40>`, so the `MyClass` instance is the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

MyClass silently inherits from Object, which mixes in Kernel.

Kernel defines puts as:

```
$stdout.puts(obj, ...)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts

Hence, you call puts, it moves to self, and cascades up to Kernel.

Comment: Very good point. What's the protocol here, should I delete my answer and leave yours(as it's more accurate)?

Comment: Actually I was wrong. `self.puts` is different from calling the `puts` method on the current class. So the first revision of my answer, which was basically saying the same as yours, was right and yours is as well.